# Why can't I access my objects member variable?

Tags: scala

I have the following class setup:

```
class MyClass {
  class MyInnerClass(memberVar: String)

  def getAInner: MyInnerClass = {
    new MyInnerClass("hello")
  }
}
```

Then I have the following code outside of the class:

```
def myFunction = {
  val a = new MyClass
  val b = a.getAInner.memberVar // value memberVar is not a member of a.MyInnerClass
}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the keyword `val` to make `memberVar` public otherwise it's a private value:

```
  class MyClass {
    class MyInnerClass(val memberVar: String)

    def getAInner: MyInnerClass = {
      new MyInnerClass("hello")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

@Noah's answer is totally correct, but I would also throw out the option of using [`case class`](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/107). [See here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/258) for some of the sugar it provides. I use it almost reflexively. In your example, it would be:

```
object MyClass {
  case class MyInnerClass(memberVar: String)

  def getAInner: MyInnerClass = {
    new MyInnerClass("hello")
  }
}

def myFunction = {
  val b = MyClass.getAInner.memberVar
}
```

I tend to do it this way because invariably, I want to take advantage of the sane defaults `case class` provides.

I also chose to use `object` for the outer type, because it doesn't have any parameters, although you may have just done that for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Can you provide some information on what exactly `case class` does? Does it basically turn instances of the class into structs?

Comment: @Max added a couple references. Depending on what you mean by "struct", I guess you could say that's correct. It mostly just auto-enable a bunch of syntactic sugar I want 99% of the time to enable idiomatic Scala functionality like pattern matching and dropping `new`, and such.

Comment: @acjay with case classes you have the option to ditch the `new` keyword, which is less idiomatic in normal-class contexts. Examples of case classes are `Some` and `None` which don't need to be `new`'ed. case classes are intended for "wrapping" objects in classes; in the case of the example above, nothing needs to be wrapped (like you would with `Some` or `Left` or `Success` for example), hence the use of case classes isn't idiomatic in this case. Another way of thinking about it would be, "if you don't need to pattern match, don't use a case class"

Comment: Maybe it's just my personal style, but the vast majority of my classes end up being data containers, except perhaps the outermost application classes. Maybe "idiomatic" was a poor word to use, because Scala supports a whole bunch of idioms. But the data-centric style is an idiom it's very well suited for, due to `case class`, `match`, and other features. I think you make a fair point. I just find that *almost* everywhere, `case class` gives me functionality I'll eventually use, while also obviating a whole lot of noise, like the `val` annotations for constructor parameters.